# QinQ tunneling more than one VLAN as a provider + is it possible to send QinQ tunneling on the same port where L2 tagged works

Tags: vlan, switching, qinq

I have done some QinQ's tunneling in my history but always there was only one customer, so situation was clear for me how to configure it. I mean access dot1q port to the customer and the rest are trunk.

Right now situation is different because one of the customers wants from us 3 QinQ transmissions. That's why I'm going to ask question - is it possible to configure 3 QinQ transmissions with 3 different SVLAN's on one single port without using "Selective QinQ" to all the VLANs could go through? Or this is possible only on classic L2 transmission?

If it's not possible does every QinQ tunnel have to go from another port on switch and I need another physical connection with customer? And is there any possibility to pass through QinQ SVLAN on the same port where normal L2 tagged VLAN's are?

[edit] Is it possible to make configuration like that on Cisco Nexus 3064-X?

Comment: Care to mention which device type (make/model) you need to configure?

Comment: @Zac67 any model I think. My boss told me that we need to configure it and it doesn't matter what device it is. Maybe it's the time to learn Cisco and choose Nexus 3064-X. Right now in our server room we have 2x Edge-corE ECS4510-28F, 1x Edge-corE ECS4510-28T and 1x TP-Link TL-SX1008. I don't mention old 3COM 4500 switches.

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. You might want to try on [hardwarerecs.se] or choose a model yourself and come back here.

Answer (score 2):

With a switch capable of restricting S-VLAN tagging on a port to certain VLIDs, you can directly trunk that to the customer for double tagging. Note that the client would require a QinQ capable device themselves.

If you can't safely restrict the S-VLAN tags to those assigned to the client you'll need to use separate ports - either by running separate lines or by using a CPE switch of yours as breakout.